# подскажите про контекст this и как в моем примере применить call

Tags: javascript

```
 var user = {
    name: 'Иван',
    age: 16,

    runUpAge: function () {

        setInterval(function () { 

            this.age = ++this.age;

            console.log(this.age);

        }, 1000);

    }

}
user.runUpAge();
```

Comment: Не ясна суть вопроса. Можно конкретнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дайте угадаю, вы хотите что бы функция `runUpAge` меняла поле `age` у объекта, а она не меняет, к тому же вообще ошибки выкидывать может.

Почему же так? Потому что вы используете `setInterval` и анонимную функцию, которая **не сохраняет** ссылку на `this`. Решения два

1) Старое

```
 var user = {
    name: 'Иван',
    age: 16,

    runUpAge: function () {
        var self = this; // руками сохраняем ссылку

        setInterval(function () { 
            self.age = ++self.age;

            console.log(self.age);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
user.runUpAge();
```

2) Модное, новое
В спецификации es6 ввели стрелочные функции, которые сохраняют ссылку на тот `this`, в контексте которого они были созданы

```
 var user = {
    name: 'Иван',
    age: 16,

    runUpAge: function () {
        setInterval(() => { 
            this.age = ++this.age;

            console.log(this.age);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
user.runUpAge();
```

Comment: Да . Спасибо добрый человек

Comment: @Anon, пометьте ответ, как верный, если он вам подходит

Comment: _Решения два_ - там чуть больше решений :)